# Why does the bench in this image stop rotating even tho the torque in the left is higher, and what formula is used to calculate torque in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque, angular-velocity

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5OaC.jpg]https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5OaC.jpg

since the the lever is balanced shouldn't the torques on both sides be equal?
if so, how are the torques calculated in this case

Comment: Observe that the pivot point is not in-line with the weights, but sits above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the torques are not equal. The left weight is 7 blocks away from the midpoint and the right one is 8 blocks away, so the torque is not the same, given that the masses are equal. Therefore I'm not sure what you are asking exactly?

Comment: if the torques aren't equal isn't the lever supposed to keep rotating clockwise?

Comment: Indeed, it is going to be in the clockwise direction, since the right object is further away from the center of rotation, i.e. torque on that side is bigger and since $\dot{\vec{L}} = \vec{T}$, there is going to be rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a minimum amount of torque needed due to friction? The torque becomes smaller as the angle increases, it would stop if it falls below the threshold.